# Java put map value's in a treeset?

Tags: java

I have a list with some beans and those beans are sorted maps. I want to iterate over maps and get the values and put them in a treeset.

```
 List<ItemBean> plannedBeans
```

This is what inside of "plannedBeans"

```
public int getItemNumber() { return unitNumber; }
public SortedMap<Date, Sequencing> getPlannedByMonth() { return sequencing; }
```

This is what is inside of the map

```
public Date getMonth() { return month; }
public double getPlanned() { return plan; }
```

I want to get all the month's in the sorted maps and throw them in one treeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your map is ready, just iterate over it and populate the TreeSet with the keys.

```
SortedMap<Date, Sequencing> map;

TreeSet<Date> set = new TreeSet();

for(Entry<Date, Sequencing> en: map.entrySet()) {
   set.add(en.getKey())
}
```

Comment: `Entry` is a nested class in `Map`.

Comment: If the goal is to have a sorted set of keys from a sorted map, you could just do `Set<Date> keys = map.keySet();`.